# Can't Get Controller to work - MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

So I'm new to PHP and I've been tasked with creating a database table, creating a model that interacts with the table, and creating a controller file that has an action function that displays all fields and data using the model. I was able to create the db table and model, but I'm having issues creating the controller. Here's what I have for the model and controller:

Model

```
Class Tyler extends ActiveRecord
{
public function tableName()
{
    return 'tyler';
}

public function rules()
{

    return array(
        array('GUITAR_NUM, YEAR', 'length', 'max'=>4),
        array('BRAND, MODEL, COLOR', 'length', 'max'=>20),
        array('GUITAR_NUM, YEAR, BRAND, MODEL, COLOR', 'safe',    on'=>'search'),
        array('GUITAR_NUM, YEAR, BRAND, MODEL, COLOR', 'required'),
    };
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'GUITAR_NUM' => 'Guitar Number',
        'BRAND' => 'Brand',
        'MODEL' => 'Model',
        'YEAR' => 'Year',
        'COLOR' => 'Color',
    };
}
}

?>
```

Controller

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\TylerModel;

Class TylerController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
        $data = Tyler::model()->findAll();

    foreach($data as $d)
    {

    echo $d->name.'<br>';

    }

    return $this->render('index',
    [
           'tyler' => $tyler,
    ]);

};
?>
```

Since I used actionIndex, all the data in the table is supposed to go to a specific url, but just get a 404 error. I've tried a bunch of different things, but nothing seems to work. Feedback/help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The First thing I've noticed in your code, is in you rendering call. You are sending `$tyler` instead of `$data`. This will surely be an error after resolving the 404 status.

About the 404 status, are you using UrlManager rules. Usually they are in `main.php` file under `config` directory in Yii2 project (Looks like Yii2 app to me). If it's the case, can you reply with the related code?

Comment: <?php

Class TylerController extends Controller
{
 public function actionIndex()
 {
  $model = TylerModel::model()->findAll();

  $this->render('index', array('tyler' => $model));
 }
}

?>

Comment: The 404 status was resolved and I tried fixing the controller, but I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''=>'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: Can you reply with the view file?